# Asynchronous C# WriteAsync - does it copy buffer before returning?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, pipe

Supposing I have this:

```
public Task WriteByteArray(byte[] pBytes)
{
    return m_pPipeStream.WriteAsync(pBytes, 0, pBytes.Length);
}
```

where m_pPipeStream is C#'s PipeStream...

It's not clear from any of the documentation or examples if the underlying system COPIES the given pBytes before returning. In other words, do I need to hold onto pBytes while it's writing out, or did the kernel take a snapshot of it, then return? I have no idea. I'm asking this question because I didn't see any current questions that addressed this simply and directly.

Comment: The code for `PipeStream.BeginWriteCore` is far too complicated for me to delve into it properly, but you're welcome to have a look yourself: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/IO/Pipes/PipeStream.cs

Comment: At a glance the buffer is fixed and a pointer to it passed to `UnsafeNativeMethods.WriteFile`, so I'm seeing no copies. What is your use case by the way? Are you queuing up a read into the same buffer instance while a `WriteByteArray` call is in flight? If that's the case you *could* rotate 2 identically sized buffer arrays. That will allow you to reduce buffer allocations without depending on a particular `PipeStream` implementation (which, as you already said, is undocumented with regards to buffer copy).

Comment: I'm surprised that it's NOT copying the data, because I'm using it in a manner that repeatedly sends the same byte [] to WriteAsync, with different bytes in it, and I don't see it messing up yet. If I was to call a normal C++ Pipe w/o overlapped, then it WOULD copy before returning. But if I was to use an overlapped call, I need to leave the buffer alone until the overlapped buffer is done. I'm surprised that C# doesn't spell it out that one needs to leave the buffer alone!

Comment: I think it's because parallel reading and writing is a bit of a corner case, even in the `async` world. Most people would `await PipeStream.WriteAsync(...)` before overwriting the buffer - at which point it's safe to do so anyway. Why do I think so? Because even the framework's default implementation of `Stream.CopyToAsync(Stream)` does exactly that (it awaits a read from source stream to buffer, then awaits buffer write to the target stream, then loops).

Comment: ... so performing an additional buffer copy along the way would just slow things down with no benefit to the majority of use cases.

Comment: Kirill, perhaps I misunderstand you, but the c# WriteAsync IS the "corner case" you describe. It's (apparently) default using Overlapped ideology under the covers. If you have to protect the contents of the buffer you just sent, then it's "parallel writing" by default. Calling WriteAsync then immediately awaiting the Task is forcing the write to be synchronous, but that's not (at all) how to get the best performance out of the pipe system. By what I'm doing, it should be getting the best performance, but it should also require I don't mess with the buffer while it's being written.

Comment: Just a clarification: which `PipeStream` are we talking about? The `System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream` or some kind of producer-consumer synchronisation mechanism (like the one found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16011/PipeStream-a-Memory-Efficient-and-Thread-Safe-Stre)? If it's the latter one, I have thrown together an alternative suggestion for you - it's posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Async functions in general do not make copies before returning.

However, you don't need to 'hold on to it', because the function will do that (in fact .NET almost always holds onto whatever it needs).

What you need to do is make sure that you don't *change the contents* after it returns and before it completes, as this will make it indeterminate which version of the data (or a mix of both) gets used.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to keep reference of pBytes. WriteAsync will keep that till needed. You can immediately release pByte reference. However, WriteAsync will only keep the reference and NOT the copy of pBytes, so make sure that you don't change the bytes of pBytes until WriteAsync finishes.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like `System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream`.

If you're using your `PipeStream` (whatever that might be) as a handover point between async producer and consumer streams, you can actually do away with it entirely and roll your own parallel copy mechanism.

In its simplest form here's what it'll look like:

```
public static async Task ParallelCopyAsync(Stream source, Stream target, int bufferSize = 4096)
{
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    byte[] writeBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    Task writeTask = null;
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
    {
        if (writeTask != null) {
            await writeTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        Array.Copy(readBuffer, 0, writeBuffer, 0, bytesRead);

        writeTask = target.WriteAsync(writeBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    if (writeTask != null) {
        await writeTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

However, as this requires 2 buffers to be allocated anyway, we can simply rotate them (as per my original comment) instead of copying from read buffer to write buffer. With that and a few other optimisations our pipeline will look like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ardex.IO
{
    public static class StreamUtil
    {
        // Taken from .NET source.
        // Largest multiple of 4096 that is still smaller
        // than the large object heap threshold (85K).
        private const int DefaultCopyBufferSize = 81920;

        public static async Task ParallelCopyAsync(Stream source, Stream target, int bufferSize = DefaultCopyBufferSize, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            if (target == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(target));
            if (bufferSize < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(bufferSize));

            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            byte[] standbyBuffer = null; // Allocated only if source is not empty.
            Task writeTask = null;
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize, ct).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
            {
                if (writeTask != null) {
                    await writeTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
                }

                // Any code after WriteAync will potentially execute
                // in parallel with the write. We cannot mutate the
                // buffer until this writeTask instance is awaited.
                writeTask = target.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead, ct);

                // Swap buffers.
                byte[] tmp = standbyBuffer;
                standbyBuffer = buffer;
                buffer = tmp ?? new byte[bufferSize];
            }

            if (writeTask != null)
            {
                // Writing final chunk.
                await writeTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```